# How does SQL Server process the following query?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I was making some queries to the database called: Northwind that is available to make proves, if you download it from the official site, I performed the following query:

```
SELECT C.CategoryName NAME,
    P.CATEGORYID CODE, 
    COUNT(*) 'PIECES',
    SUM(UnitPrice*UnitsInStock) 'AMOUNT'
FROM 
    Northwind.dbo.Categories C, Northwind.dbo.[products] P
WHERE
    P.CategoryID = C.CategoryID
AND 
    P.CategoryID>2
GROUP BY
    P.CategoryID, C.CategoryName
HAVING SUM(UnitPrice*UnitsInStock)>10000
ORDER BY 'AMOUNT' DESC;
```

The query is giving me the right results:

```
NAME            CODE        PIECES      AMOUNT
--------------- ----------- ----------- ---------------------
Seafood         8           12          13010.35
Dairy Products  4           10          11271.20
Confections     3           13          10392.20
```

The fact is that I can't figure out, how does SQL Server compute that query, since many operations are involved, In some point SQL Server has to generate a temporary data base to perform the `HAVING`:

```
HAVING SUM(UnitPrice*UnitsInStock)>10000
```

I would like to receive an explanation about the order that takes SQL Server to perform the query, I mean what is the first and last operation that SQL Server perform besides I can't figure out how does it know that has to apply the operation called SUM to the table called: products,

```
SUM(UnitPrice*UnitsInStock) 'AMOUNT'
```

I am not specifying that however is computing well the operation, also the `COUNT` for me is very ambiguous but is giving me the correct result, I really appreciate any detailed explanation of how does it computes this query, thanks for the support.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will have to look at logical order processing of a query by Itzik Ben-Gan ,he [dedicated a whole chapter](http://tsql.solidq.com/books/tk70461/) and explained in detail each step..The [link is here](http://sqlmag.com/sql-server/logical-query-processing-what-it-and-what-it-means-you)...

Below are the clauses that may execute in logical order and output of each clause is presented to the clause in next phase..

```
5 SELECT 5.2 DISTINCT 7 TOP <TOP_spec>
                                  5.1 <select_list>
                              1 FROM <table_operators: JOIN, APPLY, PIVOT, UNPIVOT>
                              2 WHERE <predicate>
                              3 GROUP BY <definition_of_grouping_sets>
                              4 HAVING <predicate>
                              6 ORDER BY <order_by_list>
                              7 OFFSET <offset_spec> FETCH <fetch_spec>
```

Comment: Thanks @TheGrameiswar, this was really helpful,

Comment: @TheGameriswar, Just one quick question, I was reading the chapter and here says that the order in what I type the query clauses, is pretty different than they get logically interpreted, and the figure that you put here is representing the logical order, is that right?

Comment: thanks for the support, I will read the chapter to understand more,

Comment: Np,glad you find answer.also please look here to ask a good question  :https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will improve my future questions,